# DIV height and width remains the same on redirected pages

Tags: permalinks

Basically, I made the post boxes smaller (height and width) on my tumblr's main page so that users won't have to scroll down to read through blogs. I tend to write lengthy blogs. What I did was lowered the height and width of my post boxes, added an overflow:hidden property (so that my lengthy texts won't go outside the divs), and permalinked them so that they can read the full posts on another page instead.

My problem is, since I adjusted the height and width of the post box on the main page, the height and width of the post box on the redirected page is also the same. My question is, there a way that I can just adjust the post box height and width ONLY on my main page and not on redirected pages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, find the class or id of the body tag for your main page. (if it has one, if not you would just need to add one)

for example if the home page has this  (*you can find this easily by viewing page source and looking for the opening body tag*)

```
<body class="home-page">
```

you could do this

```
.home-page .each-post {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

So that would only change the `.each-post` on the `.home-page`, and the `.each-post` css would stay the same on the other pages.

Comment: so with your code, i don't have to do adjust the height and width on my postbox dix correct?

Comment: @Lo_MAT No you don't, I was just giving an example. You can change anything how you want it to be!!!

Comment: i put that on my body #posts {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

and the size of the posts are also the same on the other pages =(

Comment: now I just need to find out how to make my tumblr scroll horizontally. although your suggestion worked, it made my postboxes move on the left side of the screen =(

Comment: @Lo_MAT Well, so it was working how you wanted when it changed on the home page and also the other pages?  Well, use that same code from that time.. just add the .home-page in front of it.